# Shortcut to modify a hash

Tags: swift, hash

I wonder if the following can be written shorter

```
var t = [String:[Int]]()
if t["a"] == nil { t["a"] = [1] }
else { t["a"]!.append(2) }
```

That is assigning a hash value if it does not exist and re-use it else.

I know I can write a function like

```
func extend(inout t:[String:[Int]], key:String, n:Int) {
  if t[key] == nil { t[key] = [n] }
  else { t[key]!.append(n) }
}
```

but wonder if there is a more elegant way.

**Edit** Actually I was looking for a shortcut for the function but copy/pasted test code above having different init/add values.

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to append `1` if the array exists, and create `[1]` if the array doesn't exist (as implied by your `extend` function), you can use the *nil coalescing operator* `??` like so:

```
t["a"] = (t["a"] ?? []) + [1]
```

Extended example:

```
var t = [String:[Int]]()

t["a"] = (t["a"] ?? []) + [1]    // t = ["a":[1]]
t["a"] = (t["a"] ?? []) + [2]    // t = ["a":[1,2]]
t["b"] = (t["b"] ?? []) + [4]    // t = ["b":[4], "a":[1,2]]
```

Comment: Nice one too :-) But again I need to repeat the key for the hash except I use a function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fact that optional chaining returns `nil` if the
method could *not* be called:

```
if (t["a"]?.append(2)) == nil {
    t["a"] = [1]
}
```

Implementation as a generic function (which operates on the optional
dictionary value, not on the entire dictionary):

```
var t = [String:[Int]]()

func setOrAppend<T>(inout array : [T]?, initialValue : T, newValue : T) {
    if (array?.append(newValue)) == nil {
        array = [initialValue]
    }
}

println(t)                  // [:]
setOrAppend(&t["a"], 1, 2)
println(t)                  // [a: [1]]
setOrAppend(&t["a"], 1, 2)
println(t)                  // [a: [1, 2]]
```

Comment: That looks better indeed :-) Would be nice to have some "reuse" operator but that probably does not exist. Maybe in a future Swift version? I use the above pattern quite often.

Comment: @ThomasKilian: Your initial example creates an array with the value 1, or appends the (different) value 2. The second example, using the extend function, creates or appends the value 1. Which version is it that you actually need?

Comment: Actually I was looking for what the function delivers. I just was not thoroughly in editing the question. But your code works for both cases. My requirement (though not explicitly specified) was to use the hash/key only once. I hoped for some build-in method. Your answer is as correct as that from @vacawama So I up-voted both of your answers.